# C# REST API, Azure blob file zip and download stuck at 136kb and gives network error

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

When I run the code locally, it works well but when I deploy it on Azure app service it starts downloading the file but stuck at 136KB and after a long time it shows network error.

```
    public HttpResponse downloadFileZip() {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse('BLOB Connection String');
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference('Container Name');
        string Path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs('DataFile', true))
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob) || item.GetType() == typeof(CloudAppendBlob))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob)item;
                        blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
                        zip.AddEntry(blob.Name, stream.ToArray());
                    }

                }
            }

            zip.Save(Path);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", new FileInfo(Path).Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("TransferEncodingChunked", "true");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DataFile.zip");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(Path);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            return HttpContext.Current.Response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also include the error message in your question ?

Comment: What is the network error? You'd be better off moving this code into an Azure Function. When working with a generic App Service you want to keep the compute time to a minimum.

Comment: >>Failed - Network error<< this error I gets in chrome

Comment: Regarding the issue, I suggest you remote debug your web app to get the detailed error message. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio